# How can I attach a shape to a port in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, digital-design

In logic design convention, a clock input port is designated by an embedded triangle while an active low port has a bubble as shown in this [d-flip-flop](http://yang.zone/podongii_X2/html/TECHNOTE/TOOL/MANUAL/15i_doc/fndtn/ver/figures/x8599.gif) example.

Now the bubbled I/O's I can do (if somewhat counter-intuitively) using arrowhead and arrowtail. But I can't see how to make an arrowhead extend just into the port.  Ideally, this would be a characteristic of the port rather than the connecting arrow but that is a lesser concern.

Comment: You may do this in a way similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066677/in-graphviz-how-do-i-add-a-shape-in-the-middle-of-an-edge/58094960#58094960